# Finding the minimal form for an element of the free idempotent monoid in Haskell

Tags: haskell, discrete-mathematics, monoids

The [free idempotent monoid](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/FreeIdempotentMonoid.html) is like the free monoid, but quotiented by the equation *x*² = *x*; for instance, *aa* = *a*, *bcbcb* = *b(cb)(cb)* = *bcb*,

However, to find the minimal form of a word in the monoid, expansion (*x* = *x*²) as well as contraction (*x*² = x) is often required, so not every squarefree word in the language is minimal. For instance, *bacbcabc* = *bacabc*. As a result, the free idempotent monoid on a finite number of generators is finite.

What I'm looking for is an algorithm in Haskell that takes a finite word in the monoid, represented here as a [`Seq`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/containers-0.6.2.1/docs/Data-Sequence.html#t:Seq), and returns its minimal form, where minimal is defined by:

1. Shortest length, and
2. Lexicographically smallest among words of the same length.

So the signature for this method would be:

```hs
minimizeIdempotent :: Ord a => Seq a -> Seq a
minimizeIdempotent w = ...
```

From there, the definition for the `Semigroup` and `Monoid` instances would be:

```hs
newtype Idempotent a = Idempotent (Seq a)
  deriving (Eq, Ord, Show)

instance Ord a => Semigroup (Idempotent a) where
  Idempotent x <> Idempotent y
    | null x = Idempotent y
    | null y = Idempotent x
    | otherwise = Idempotent (minimizeIdempotent (x <> y))

  stimes n x = case compare n 0 of
    LT -> error "stimes (Idempotent): negative count"
    EQ -> Idempotent mempty
    GT -> x

instance Ord a => Monoid (Idempotent a) where
  mempty = Idempotent mempty
  mappend = (<>)
```

Comment: Do you know how to implement this algorithm in any language (even pseudocode)? If so, take a stab at translating that to Haskell yourself, and show us where you got stuck. If not, perhaps making this language-agnostic, or even asking on a sister site like the CS stackexchange, would make more sense.

Answer (score 3):

The proof of Theorem 2.4.1 in "Combinatorics on Words" by M. Lothaire appears to have some relevant clues. For a given word, we pull out four pieces of it:

1. The longest prefix which does not contain all the letters that the whole word does.
2. The next letter.
3. The longest suffix which does not contain all the letters that the whole word does.
4. The previous letter.

Write *w .= (p, a, b, q)* when *p* and *q* are the appropriate prefix and suffix, respectively, of *w*, and *a* and *b* are the next and previous letter, respectively. For example, *bacbcabc .= (ba, c, a, bc)*, *aaabaa .= (aaa, b, b, aa)*, and *abcd .= (abc, d, a, bcd)*.

If *w1 .= (p1, a1, b1, q1)* and *w2 .= (p2, a2, b2, q2)*, they prove in Claim (iii) on page 34 that *w1 ~ w2* iff *p1 ~ p2*, *a1 = a2*, *b1 = b2*, and *q1 ~ q2*. (I am using *~* for the congruence relation induced by the equation *x ~ xx*, so that I can distinguish between exact word equality and quotiented equality.) We can use this to create an algorithm for computing a canonical form for a given word *w* as follows:

1. Compute *p, a, b, q* such that *w .= (p, a, b, q)*.
2. Recursively compute canonical forms *p'* for *p* and *q'* for *q*. (Base case: the canonical form for the empty word is the empty word.)
3. Find the longest suffix of *p'a* which is a prefix of *bq'*; call this *s*, and the leftovers *t*, so that *p'a = ts*.
4. Return *tbq'*.

I believe this algorithm is correct by a relatively simple inductive argument. By "correct", I mean that *w1 ~ w2* iff *f(w1) = f(w2)*, where *f* is the function described above. It is not clear that *f* produces the minimal representative of the equivalence class by the ordering you propose, but perhaps correctness in this sense is enough for your needs.

(Strictly speaking, steps 3 and 4 above aren't completely necessary for correctness. You could just return *p'abq'* and get the same guarantee. But the resulting representatives would be very long by comparison to the proposed algorithm above.)

This algorithm is not very efficient! You can think of this as making two recursive calls, each with words with one fewer unique letters, so this takes time that is at least exponential in the size of the alphabet of the original word. Yikes. You might want to think of a few easy cases to fast-path. For example, when all duplicate letters are immediately adjacent to each other, deleting the adjacent duplicates canonicalizes. Another fast path that might be useful: when canonicalizing *wx*, where you know *w* and *x* are already canonicalized, then *w* and *x* can themselves be base cases if you happen to reach them during recursion, and it may be that you can think of some ways to cheaply identify additional substrings of *w* and *x* that are suitable base cases.

Comment: I read that paper myself, but I couldn't figure out how *a* and *b* were chosen. Thanks for the explanation!

Comment: Thus far, I've figured out as base cases: (1) If |alpha(x)| = |x|, then min(x) = x; (2) if a ∉ x and a ∉ y, then min(xay) = (min(x))a(min(y)); (3) base cases for |x| < 4 or |alpha(x)| < 3. Right now, I'm wondering if a fast way to eliminate squares would help, and if so what that way is.